# Abrir .bat desde html

Tags: javascript, html, cmd, msdos

Intento abrir un .bat desde un link de chrome.

Es para un html(bookmarks) que utilizamos en la empresa y dependiendo que URLs hay que abrirlas con un navegador u otro.

El bat contendría lo siguiente:

```
start iexplorer http://www.google.com
```

Hasta ahora lo que he hecho es lo siguiente:

```
<a href="../Open.bat">Cliente 1</a>
```

Y para mi sorpresa, en vez de ejecutar el .bat, lo abre en esa misma pestaña como texto plano.
He probado con un boton, y el evento onClick, ejecutar un js, pero o bien no he sabido hacerlo o no se puede.

```
var wshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
wshShell.Run("../Open.bat");
```

**¿Qué error estoy cometiendo? o ¿Qué me estoy dejando?**

Comment: ¿El bat donde se encuentra, en servidor o cliente?

Comment: Cliente, ruta predefinida pongamos por ejemplo `C:\empresa\bookmarks\Open.bat`

Comment: No se puede. Sería un fallo de seguridad enorme si desde un link en un sitio arbitrario pudieses ejecutar código en la máquina del visitante.

Comment: Nos resultaría indiferente que el .bat esté en local/servidor.
Estoy totalmente de acuerdo @amenadiel por eso pregunto si se puede

Comment: A ver si me he enterado: ¿quieres que ciertas páginas se abran en otro navegador? ¿Es por un tema de compatibilidad?

Comment: No se puede. Aunque este en la misma máquina, el browser no puede ejecutar ni ver los archivos locales del visitante. La única manera sería que el backend recibiera una petición y ejecutara (por ejemplo mediante un shell_exec) el comando en el contexto del backend. Pero eso debes hacerlo apuntando a una ruta del backend que haga ese trabajo. Al apuntar al `.bat` para el browser es simplemente texto.

Comment: Así es @PabloLozano

Comment: @PabloLozano No consigo lo que quería pero resuelve una de mis dudas, si es posible o no ejecutar un archivo desde html. Gracias!

Comment: Con la extensión [IE tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd) de google chrome, consigo abrir ese link en modo compatibilidad con IE7 así consigo ejecutar el .bat